# position: sticky não funciona no meu header

Tags: html, css, posicionamento

Galera, tenho um header que o position: sticky não está funcionando e eu não estou entendendo o por quê.

HTML

```
<header class="header_bg">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#">UNEARTH</a>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
.header {
background-color: white;
padding: 40px 0;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
flex-wrap: wrap;
width: 100%;
position: sticky;
top: 0;}
```

Alguém pode me explicar? Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, seu container não tem tag de fechamento está faltando um `</div>`

Depois vc colocou o `position:sticky` no elemento errado, vc colocou em um "filho" e deveria estar no pai de todos, ou seja na tag `<header>`

Testa ai com esse ajuste para vc ver

```css
body {
  height: 150vh; margin: 0;
}
.header_bg {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
.header {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 40px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header class="header_bg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="#">UNEARTH</a>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```